# Maven scm tag and credentials - multiple accounts on same host

Tags: maven

When working with sites such a GitHub or Bitbucket it is not uncommon to have more than one account on those sites.

I would normally put my credentials into the system-wide `settings.xml`, such as

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github.com</id>
      <username>user1</username>
      <password>mysecret</password>
    </server>
```

and this will work fine with the standard Maven <scm> section in the POM. The domain name from the `<developerConnection>` will be matched with `<id>` from the appropriate server in settings.xml file. Bingo!

But what if I have more than one account on the same domain?
(and still want credentials to be in `settings.xml`). I cannot understand how Maven will do the matching then. My URL in the `<scm>` section include "username@host" notation so surely Maven would have enough information to do an appropriate match in `settings.xml`.

I've tried the below format which in my mind would be the logical way that Maven would support this:

```
<settings>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>user1@github.com</id>
      <username>user1</username>
      <password>mysecret</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>user2@github.com</id>
      <username>user2</username>
      <password>mysecret</password>
    </server>

    <!-- default if no username in scm section -->
    <server>
      <id>github.com</id>
      <username>user1</username>
      <password>mysecret</password>
    </server>
```

But that didn't work.

Any idea on how this is done?

Surely I cannot be the first in the world with more than one account on same VCS host ... and using Maven.

### UPDATE

I've reviewed the code of the [Maven SCM Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/components/scm/maven-scm-plugin/). There's absolutely no support for what I write above. What happens today is matching `<id>` tag with the hostname part as given in the SCM URL. The comparison is done strict, i.e. not even case-insensitive. If a port number was given in the URL then that is included as well and must match the `<id>` tag, e.g. `myhost:8080`.

I've created an [Enhancement Request (SCM-826)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SCM-826?) on this issue.

Comment: Are you talking about [Maven's `settings.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers) when you write `server.xml`?

Comment: @GeroldBroser. Yes, thanks for pointing that out. Don't know what happened to my brain when I made those typos. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you authenticate through SSH. If user1 and user 2 have the same public key, they could be authenticated without `settings.xml` file

Comment: As far as I can tell SSH isn't a supported protocol in Maven SCM Plugin when used with Hg. [link](http://maven.apache.org/components/scm/mercurial.html) and more specifically [looking at the source](https://github.com/apache/maven-scm/blob/master/maven-scm-providers/maven-scm-provider-hg/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/scm/provider/hg/repository/HgScmProviderRepository.java). On Git it is indeed supported. Bottom line: This wouldn't be a solution, except for Git and in that case only if your Git repo exposes ssh as a possible protocol.

Comment: Good point. I saw you wrote 'Bitbucket' and 'Github' and I thought that a solution which works for me would be good for you also.